# Symfony2 REST Translation from database

Tags: symfony, translation, fosrestbundle

I am facing very difficult problem to handle my situation. Im saving title in database for en the name is title and for the translation column the name is bntitle.

now im use FosRest with jms serializer to provide the api response. but i can't find a way to send respond based on local. because it always calls the

```
getTitle()
```

method to get the title, my question is if local is en then the title key will be `getTitle()` if local is bn title should call `getBnTitle()`;

this the controller:

```
public function getAction(Content $entity, Request $request)
{
   $locale =  $request->getLocale();
   $data = array();

   $data['_embedded']['content'] = $entity;

    eturn $data;

}
```

how can I do that?

Comment: It is not a clean way of handle translation, and now you are facing the consequences of it. Is it to late to change your data model?

Comment: yes we already have more than few thousands of data in our db now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way to handle the translation for sure but if you just need this for the title attribute you can pass the local to the entity as an argument and then in `getTitle()` method you do the test.

```
public class YourEntity{
    private $locale ;
    //......

    public function setLocale($locale){
       $this->locale = $locale
    }
    public function getTitle(){ 
      // your test here 
      if ( $locale === 'bn' ) return $this->getBnTitle();
      return $title ; 
    }
```

Then in your controller :

```
public function getAction(Content $entity, Request $request)
{
   $locale =  $request->getLocale();
   // pass local to entity 
   $entity->setLocale($locale);
   $data = array();

   $data['_embedded']['content'] = $entity;

    eturn $data;

}
```

**Edit :** 
If you want a better solution there is many doctrine extensions that do the translation one of them is this 
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md

Comment: thnx it worked, but do you have better idea without using the the doctrine behavior or translation?

Comment: public function getTitle()
    {

        return $this->locale === 'bn' ? $this->getBntitle() : $this->title;
    }

I used this...